# onClick addClass 'active' slideDown overlay div, close overlay div onClick next div

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to cobble together a script from various places on this site, but it's not working yet. What I need to happen is to click on a div and have the overlay div slide down, if a different div is clicked close the prev div and slide down the next. Here's my sort of working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G94Vm/

HTML:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="item-overlay"></div>        
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="item-overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var open = $('.item'),
    a = $('div').find('.item-overlay');
open.click(function(){
    var $this = $('.item-overlay', this),
        speed = 300;
    $this.addClass('active').slideDown(speed);
    if ($this.hasClass('active') === true) {
        $this.removeClass('active').next('.item-overlay').slideUp(speed);
    } else if (a.hasClass('active') === false) {
        $this.addClass('active').next('.item-overlay').slideDown(speed);
    } else {
        a.removeClass('active').next('.item-overlay').slideUp(speed);
        $this.addClass('active').next('.item-overlay').delay(speed).slideDown(speed);
    }
});
```

});

This is the site I'm [working on:](http://bozaandesign.com/newwebsite/) Which is just using this basic script right now:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.item', this).click(function () {
    $('.item-overlay', this).slideToggle('400', function () {
        // end animation
    });
});
```

});

I'm still learning jQuery and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Been at this for hours, any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!
John

Comment: I'm a little closer now, see updated fiddle above. Still not working quite right, first and second clicks work, then I lose the slide function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you want the `.item-overlay` div inside to slide down when its parent `.item` div is clicked on, and if there are any other `.item-overlay` divs visible for all of them to close up?

Here's a working example. The slideUp animation is a little buggy for me at the moment, but this might give you what you're after (*updated to use slideToggle instead of slideDown*):

```
$('.item').click(function () {
    $(this).find('.item-overlay').slideToggle('300').addClass('active');
    $(this).siblings().find('.active').each(function () {
        $(this).slideUp('300').removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, raphaelvalerio, that works very well. Any idea how to get this to slide back up if you click the 'active' div?

Comment: Yes, simply change `slideDown` on line 2 of my code sample to `slideToggle`. I've updated the answer accordingly. Hope it helps you!

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks, raphaelvalerio! Perfect. The script also has the nice function of closing the layer after you click on a link and then come back to the page. I appreciate the help, been working on this all day and you figured it out in a so little time.

Comment: Very happy to help! Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I just updated the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/G94Vm/10

You don't need all this `if` statements.
Just close all overlays before you slide down the next.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.item').click(function(){
    var element = $('.item-overlay', this);
    var speed = 300;
    $('.item-overlay').removeClass('active').slideUp(speed);
    element.addClass('active').slideDown(speed);
});
});
```

And you need to remove

```
.item-overlay {
    display:none;
}
```

because you want to slide it down and thats not possible if it's hidden until it's slided down.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, looks like there are several ways to do this. I'll give these a try and see what one works best for this situation.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work pretty well, but when you click on the 'active' overlay it repeats the slideDown behavior. Also, if you click on a link on the overlay and then close that window to come back to the original site, there's a weird flicker. Any idea how to make is just slide back up? Seems like it would need a conditional.

Comment: Yeah you can check if it's allready active before slideDown. `if(!element.hasClass('active')) { element.addClass('active').slideDown(speed); }`. I can't see any flicker.

Comment: Sorry, I had a different script on there when you checked. I'll add yours back on there.

Comment: I couldn't get the conditional to work, but I appreciate the effort. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You actually use the `next` the wrong way. I've rewritten your jsFiddle so that it does the animations, stop when it should, and listen for clicks outside that should close the active overlay.

The link is : http://jsfiddle.net/alexis_tondelier/Gf2dv/

And the current JS code is :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $active,
        togglerSelector = '.item',
        toggledSelector = '.item-overlay',
        $items = $(togglerSelector),
        animationDuration = 300,
        activeClassName = 'active',
        activeStyle = {height: 300},
        notActiveStyle = {height: 0}
        hideActive = function() {
            $active && $active
                .stop()
                .animate(notActiveStyle, function() {
                    $(this).removeClass(activeClassName).hide();
                });    
            $active = void 0;        
        },
        showActive = function($element) {
            $element && ($active = $element)
                .stop()
                .show()
                .animate(activeStyle)
                .addClass(activeClassName)
        };

    $items.on('click', function(event) {
        var $this = $(this),
            $overlay = $this.children(toggledSelector),
            theSame = $overlay.is($active);
        hideActive();
        theSame || showActive($overlay);
        }
    });
    $(this).on('click', function(event) {
        var $target = $(event.target),
            isOutClick = !$target.closest(togglerSelector).length;
        isOutClick && hideActive();
    });
});
```

It should work the way you wanted.

Comment: I tried this script, can't get it working. The JHint in jfiddle shows some errors?

Comment: I forgot a ',' juste after `notActiveStyle ` declaration, and then it works on every navigator. And even with this error, since not using strict mode, it was working but just using global variables instead of local ones. jsFiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/alexis_tondelier/Gf2dv/

Comment: JHint just doesn't like `boolean && functionCall` style. But it doesn't throw any error and works well.